# jetty transparent proxy always returns 403 forbidden

Tags: java, maven, proxy, jetty, transparentproxy

I am trying to use the transparent proxy provided by jetty.

This is my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="WebApp_9"
     version="2.4"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>googleProxy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.ProxyServlet$Transparent</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ProxyTo</param-name>
        <param-value>http://www.google.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>Prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/google</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>googleProxy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/google/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and this is the pom.xml (I am using maven):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>JettyProxySample</groupId>
<artifactId>JettyProxySample</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>JettyProxySample Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.M4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>JettyProxySample</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I expect the proxy to forward a request like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/JettyProxySample/google/search?q=hello
```

to this:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=hello
```

But when I try that url in browser, I always get this:

```
HTTP ERROR: 403

FORBIDDEN
RequestURI=/JettyProxySample/google/search

Powered by Jetty://
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you use a transparent proxy. What the IP address?

Comment: @Roman C  I am just trying to figure out how to use it. And sorry, what do you mean by "What the IP address?"?

Comment: For this matter you need to read the docu.

Comment: For such a simple use case, I would consider using Smiley's HTTP Proxy Servlet: 
https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to toss an answer onto here, do not use a milestone release that is years old.

- 7.6.7.v20120910 for jetty7
- 8.1.7.v20120910 for jetty8

I know lots of folks using the proxy servlet in both versions successfully, just not something that was from the initial migrations from codehaus to eclipse...there was a serious amount of code churn back then so I would not be surprised if this isn't working correctly for you.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the source code helps.  :)

The problem is, you don't have your proxy servlet set at the root of the web 
server, but inside of an application, thus your Prefix parameter needs to 
include the entire prefix, context-name of web application included...

Prefix/YOUR_WEB_APP_CONTEXT/google

[see also](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jetty.support/14700)